# What is the plastic-rubber polymer "sticky rubber coating" that always seems to fail?

Tags: logitech-mouse

This is a plastic question about commodity hardware. Logitech mice and many other popular peripherals have an sprayed on or molded overcoat. It's a plastic of sort that turns into glue and comes off leaving shiny spots. Tends to fail entirely within 5 years, with the first sign of failure being around 2 years in.

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=14FR2xSCmZ4) they call a "sticky rubber coating" so I'll go with that. It feels great when you buy it, and it's a great example of designed to fail. What is this horrible substance called?

Comment: It's just a "rubberized coating" See [cleaning - How to cure "stickiness" on walkie-talkie rubber components - Lifehacks Stack Exchange](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/19239/how-to-cure-stickiness-on-walkie-talkie-rubber-components) for cleaning tips.

Answer (score 0):

It's not plastic, but rather rubber. A common name for it is
"spray-on rubber".
It feels great when it's new.

Unfortunately, this rubber just melts under the right conditions.
This can be caused by high surrounding temperatures, or even by sweaty hands.

You may get the sticky rubber coating off, once it goes sticky,
by rubbing it with a cleaning solution that contains at least 90% alcohol.